# DoubleRenderError after upgrading to Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After upgrading my Rails 4 app to Rails 4.2 I am getting this error:

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in InvoicesController#download
>
> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

This is the controller in question:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def download
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by(:download_code => params[:id])
    if @invoice
      respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf { |pdf| render_pdf("attachment") }
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "File cannot be found."
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
  end

  private

  def render_pdf(disposition = "inline")
    pdf = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice, view_context)    
    options = { :filename => invoice_filename(@invoice), :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => disposition }
    send_data(pdf.render, options)
  end

end
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a `before_action` lurking in `ApplicationController`? Another possibly stupid off-the-cuff idea: try renaming `render_pdf` to `create_pdf`.

Comment: Have u tried by removing `respond_to` block and by keeping only this `render_pdf("attachment") }` ?

Comment: @janfoeh: Thanks but no, there's no `before_action` in this case. And renaming didn't do the trick either.

Comment: How does your `InvoicePdf` renderer class look like? I have some custom PDF renderer classes, and I remember them breaking when I upgraded from 4.0 to 4.2, although in a different manner. Here is my [Rails 4.2/WickedPDF-based renderer](https://gist.github.com/janfoeh/ae639418a321bf70520a), in case it helps.

Comment: Hmm. Prawn doesn't seem to depend in any way on ActionView as my solution does, so it can't be related to the `render_to_string` changes that popped up in Rails 4.1. Quite sorry, but no great insights here then.

Comment: Never mind and thanks for at least trying! :-)

Comment: @AmitSharma: Yeah, but that won't work either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I simply had to add `and return` at the end of the line to get this to work. I am not 100% sure why this is necessary, though. Maybe someone can shed some light on this.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf { |pdf| render_pdf("attachment") and return }
end
```